# Assert batch not in keys and ptr not in keys

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-geometric

I'm running PyTorch Geometric (1.7.2) wrapped with PyTorch Lightning, and I get the assertion error above. I can't copy the whole stack trace, but the error is thrown by

```
return self.collate_fn(data)
```

I saw [this article with the same error](https://github.com/nicolas-chaulet/torch-points3d/issues/606) but it did not help. I would appreciate any tips on how to fix this.

Comment: You need to provide the full error backtrace as well as the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your data has some undesired attributes: 'batch' or 'ptr'. In order to check that, you can print 'data' directly.

Then to solve the error, you can easily turn off the 'batch' or 'ptr' attributes by:

```
for g in data:
    g.batch = None
    g.ptr = None
```